# How to fix VLOOKUP when it returns the incorrect value from the bottom of the list?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

In Google Sheets, I am having trouble with a VLOOKUP function.

- `range` argument `A2:B` contains text strings.
- `search_key` is in column C, example, `C2`
- `index` argument is (column) `2`, which is equivalent to `B2:B`

### Current Formula

- I thought my syntax was correct, but my VLOOKUP formula returns the wrong value.
- In column A are the textual search keys and in column B are the values that I wish to return. Values are sorted.
- Note that `#value!` in IFNA is intentional. I want to use the results in a TOCOL function and it was not treating `""` as a blank ("ignore blanks") so I replaced `""` with `#value!` and used "ignore error" instead.

```
=ifna(vlookup($C2,$A$2:$B,2),#value!)
```

### Sample Data

- `B2:B` strings are actually 50 characters in length (not 10); they've been shortened below to save space

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **search_key** | **list of values** | **user_input** | **current formula** | **desired result** |
| **2** | mm | **1101000000** | mm | `0100000000` | **1101000000** |
| **3** | mɱ | 1100000000 |  | #VALUE! |  |
| **4** | mn | **1100001000** | mn | `0100000000` | **1100001000** |
| **5** | mɳ | 1100000010 |  | #VALUE! |  |
| **6** | ʙʛ | `0100000000` |  | #VALUE! |  |

[Link to Test Spreadsheet illustrating problem](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-O2tt3vhrNJCx7ec8ZmzjY6sp19ucAFsBO2utqTeErU/edit#gid=2100307022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basic Formula

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2, A2:B, 2, 0))      // Data Unsorted

=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2, SORT(A2:B), 2))   // Data Unsorted

=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2, A2:B, 2))         // Sorted data (asc.)
```

### Single Array Formula in `D2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, A2:B, 2 ,0)))        // Data Unsorted

=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, SORT(A2:B), 2)))  // Data Unsorted

=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, A2:B, 2)))           // Sorted data (asc.)
```

### Explantation

1. The [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) function's `is_sorted` argument refers to the `range` argument's first column, not the `index` argument's column.
2. That column needs to be sorted ascending either manually, or using the [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) function. Otherwise, the [optional] `is_sorted` argument should be set to `FALSE` / `0`  because it defaults to `TRUE` if omitted:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
   ```
3. [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en) does not see an empty string `""` as a blank value.  By contrast the [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) function will treat `""` and blanks the same way: `LEN("")=0`.
4. To return a truly blank value, you can simply omit the `value_if_na_error` argument from the [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en) function:

   ```
   Syntax:  IFNA(value, [value_if_na_error])

   Replace:  IFNA(value,"")
        By:  IFNA(value)
     or By:  IFNA(value,)
   ```